# Find replace numeric list on notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have this huge block of code.

```
        <item id="P2_0102_01.jpg" href="images/01_02/P2_0102_55.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg"/>
        <item id="P2_0102_01.jpg" href="images/01_02/P2_0102_56.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg"/>
        <item id="P2_0102_01.jpg" href="images/01_02/P2_0102_57.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg"/>
        <item id="P2_0102_01.jpg" href="images/01_02/P2_0102_58.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg"/>
        <item id="P2_0102_01.jpg" href="images/01_02/P2_0102_59.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg"/>
        <item id="P2_0102_01.jpg" href="images/01_02/P2_0102_60.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg"/>
        <item id="P2_0102_01.jpg" href="images/01_02/P2_0102_61.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg"/>
        <item id="P2_0102_01.jpg" href="images/01_02/P2_0102_62.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg"/>
        <item id="P2_0102_01.jpg" href="images/01_02/P2_0102_63.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg"/>
        <item id="P2_0102_01.jpg" href="images/01_02/P2_0102_64.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg"/>
        <item id="P2_0102_01.jpg" href="images/01_02/P2_0102_65.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg"/>
        <item id="P2_0102_01.jpg" href="images/01_02/P2_0102_66.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg"/>
        <item id="P2_0102_01.jpg" href="images/01_02/P2_0102_67.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg"/>
        <item id="P2_0102_01.jpg" href="images/01_02/P2_0102_68.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg"/>
        <item id="P2_0102_01.jpg" href="images/01_02/P2_0102_69.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg"/>
        <item id="P2_0102_01.jpg" href="images/01_02/P2_0102_70.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg"/>
```

And what I would like to ask is how to replace all the `01.jpg`'s with `55, 56, 57, etc` with Notepad++. I was informed in chat that it was possible with CTRL+H and regular expressions but I have absolutely no knowledge of regex whatsoever, but I'd like to learn.

So... how is this done? If it's okay, I'd like some explanations too so I can learn something. :)

Answer (score 1):

search this :  `01(?=\.jpg)(.*)(\d{2}).jpg`

replace with : `\2\1\2.jpg`

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/hP7kC3

Answer (score 1):

You could replace

```
id="(.*_)\d+.jpg" href="(.*_(\d+)).jpg"
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

By

```
id="\1\3.jpg" href="\2.jpg"
```

- Demo on [RegExr](http://regexr.com/38n3c)
- Visualization by [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/7HOjH4cBwEzwaVE7)

Answer (score 0):

**Find what:** `_(\d+)(.jpg.*_)(\d+).jpg`

**Replace with:** `_$3$2$3.jpg`

**Explanation:** First define three captures by using `()`, in which the first is the `01` that you want to replace, the second is the content between `01` and `56...70` and the third is the content that you want to replace with, i.e. `56...70`. Then you just need to use the third capture to fill the first one, i.e. `_$3$2$3.jpg` instead of `_$1$2$3.jpg` (the original). Done!

Answer (score 0):

Search: item id=\".+\" href="(.+)" media
Replace: item id="\1" href="\1" media

It will search for a matching string with

item id="{{some characters}}" href="{{some characters}}" media

the second character group (.+) is a matching group what you can use in your replace pattern (that is the first one, so you can reference it as \1

The replace string says that replace the matching string with the given string, where use the first matching group at the given positions \1